# Check if a timestamp column value is more than six months old

Tags: mysql

I have a table t_windows_updates which has two columns ci_id and update_installed_on. Table will be having all the windows updates happened to all the assets in my environment.
Data will be like

```
ci_id| update_installed_on

1         |   1452364200000

1         |   1453055400000

2         |   1441650600000

2         |   1441650600000

2         |   1441650600000
```

I want to get all ci_ids for which the latest update didn't happen in the last six months.

My Query is

```
SELECT t.ci_id FROM `t_windows_update` t
       GROUP BY t.ci_id
       HAVING MAX(t.update_installed_on)<= (NOW() - INTERVAL 6 MONTH);
```

It is running but getting wrong results.

Comment: I am trying to put the comma separated ci ids into a column I am getting an error saying Subquery returns more than 1 row UPDATE metrics SET id_list=(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT t.ci_id SEPARATOR ',') FROM `t_windows_update` t GROUP BY t.ci_id HAVING MAX(t.update_installed_on) / 1000 <= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 6 MONTH))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is the date format.

I think this is a unix format in milliseconds.  So, this suggests something like:

```
having max(t.update_installed_on) <= UNIT_TIMESTAMP(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 6 MONTH) * 1000
```

I realize that the above could have overflow issues with integers, so let's go the other way:

```
having max(t.update_installed_on) / 1000 <= UNIT_TIMESTAMP(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 6 MONTH)
```

Comment: I need to update some table with all these ids comma separated. SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT t.ci_id SEPARATOR ',' ) FROM `t_windows_update` t GROUP BY t.ci_id HAVING MAX(t.update_installed_on) / 1000 <= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 6 MONTH) I am getting result contains more than one row error here

Comment: @Jerry . . . New questions should be asked as questions, not comments.

Comment: Sorry , since it was a part of my current question thought of asking here. Anyway I got it work :)